# My neural network gives an error and I don't know why

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm relatively new to programming neural networks and have been following a few tutorials about it before deciding to try and learn to program neural networks on my own using what i'd learnt. I've been trying to program a basic neural network just so i can learn how it works, but it keeps giving me an error. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8,(5, 5),padding="same",activation='relu',input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae','mse', 'accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=10,verbose=2)
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
str(x.shape.as_list()))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 784]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is cause `Conv2D` expects input shape to be of 4 dimensions i.e. [batch_size, height, width, channels]. You can do one thing i.e. reshape your input to the model.

```
X = X.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) # incase of single channel (grayscale)
# OR
X = X.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 3) # incase of RGB
# and then change the input shape of your `Conv2D` layer accordingly to
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8,(5, 5),padding="same",activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
# OR
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8,(5, 5),padding="same",activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,3)))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but got the error "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40 into shape (28,28,1)" Any suggestions?

Comment: share the output of X.shape

Comment: X.shape appears to be equal to (10, 4)

Comment: Then your dataset is incorrect. You need to cross-check your data from where you acquired it. Also, your dataset should consist of images. right?

Comment: I'm not really sure where I got the data from. Here's the unpickled X.pickle if it helps:
          0         1         2         3
0  0.575454  0.870410 -1.247614  1.097578
1 -0.043073  0.959476  0.324645 -1.715399
2 -0.085343 -0.266862 -0.109377 -0.677000
3 -1.127073 -0.787415 -0.900254  0.120965
4 -1.876247  0.091427  0.627204  1.709527
5 -0.677337  0.701137  1.359190 -0.342608
6  0.738300 -0.908286 -1.073818  2.013648
7 -0.755385  0.641644 -0.502232 -0.156762
8 -1.041716  0.372856 -0.197946 -1.133026
9  1.634808  0.435852  0.803350  0.020503

Comment: Yes, your dataset is wrong. You have to check where you get your dataset from and find a new dataset for your problem.

Comment: It's really weird, I just wrote the code and the data appeared. Is that normal?

Comment: Its seems I need 20 reputation to join the chat.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat Please do not use external chat services as it completely defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy At that time his question was no more relevant and I just wanted to help him. Moreover, I first create a SO chat room but his reputation is too low to be able to join. Also, the case is not reproducible so I don't think there is any need to have it here on SO.